# Using a github Personal Access Token with TortoiseSVN

Tags: git, svn, passwords, tortoisesvn, personal-access-token

Github is turning off password access next month so I have generated a personal access token (PAT).

I then try to check out a new copy of an existing repo with the URL:

https://me:ghp_blahblahblah@github.com/me/myrepo.git

where ghp_blahblahblah is my PAT. I get the following error:

> Subversion encountered a serious problem. ... In file
> 'D:\Development\SVN\Releases\TortoiseSVN-1.14.1\ext\subversion\subversion\libsvn_client\util.c'
> line 96: assertion failed (svn_uri__is_ancestor(pathrev->repos_root_url, url))

I am running the latest version of TortoiseSVN 1.14.1.

Am I missing a step? Is there another way to make this work without resorting to SSH keys, which I don't want to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to use a Subversion client to talk to Github? I'm not sure that's going to work, try [TortoiseGit](https://tortoisegit.org/).

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen yes I am and it's been supported for years.

Comment: Use the correct URL without putting your username and PAT into the URL - works perfectly for me. This particular error appears to be a bug, though.

Comment: @bahrep - how do I use the PAT if it's not in the URL? As the password when prompted by TortoiseSVN?

Comment: As a side question..... why do you use an svn client to use a git repo? I know it's supported, as you said.... but I can't help but wonder.

Comment: @eftshift0 because I use it to access work svn repos and so I am familiar with it, I like it and I like being able to use the same tool for both. I am not a fan of git.

Comment: @Andy yes, as a password when prompted. PAT is a password from the client side perspective.

Comment: @Andy I C. Just curious.

Comment: I started an email thread in dev@ Apache Subversion regarding this crash when using username:password@ in the repository URL: https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/r1fcf129e99783eb7c961826730d852e59f29971999cab61365c71f4c%40%3Cdev.subversion.apache.org%3E

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the correct URL without putting your username and PAT into the URL - works perfectly.

PAT is a password from the client side perspective. I have tested  TortoiseSVN and the svn.exe command-line client and all of them are capable of using GitHub's personal access tokens for authentication (personal and private repositories). The only difference is that - when prompted for a password - you need to enter your personal access token. If the authentication fails, please make sure that you are entering the credentials correctly:

- Username: your email
- Password: your personal access token

Please, make sure that you copy the personal access token correctly (it is possible that it is surrounded with unnecessary whitespaces).