# TortoiseSVN commit to Github Authentication

Tags: github, svn, tortoisesvn

Can someone tell me what causes or how to fix authentication issues when trying to commit files to my GitHub? Everytime I put in my username and password after trying a commit it says it's the wrong credentials. I've tried my username password email password and both won't allow me to commit using tortoise SVN. I'm able to login to GitHub web interface and commit with no problem but when I use the same credentials through tortoise SVN no luck.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68516312/761095

Answer (score 3):

GitHub has disabled using passwords for authentication over HTTP in favor of personal access tokens.  This is because while personal access tokens are restricted to only certain access, if a password is compromised, then it allows access to the entire account, including the web interface, unless 2FA is enabled (in which case a password wouldn't have worked anyway).

When you're prompted for the password, go to [the Personal Access Tokens page](https://github.com/settings/tokens), generate a token with the `repo` scope, and use it instead of your password.  Note that you'll probably want to ensure you save the password so you don't have to enter it again or memorize it.