# Cannot Checkout a branch from TortoiseSVN

Tags: github, svn, tortoisesvn

I am having trouble checkout a branch from TortoiseSVN.

Steps:

1. Right-click and select SVN Checkout.

[image]

2. Copy the repository URL and then press OK.

[image]

3. Prompts for username and password. Even though I have provided the correct credentials, I am unable to checkout the branch due to Authentication issue.

[image]

Have anyone came across with this issue? Appreciate your help.

Comment: Most probably it's password-vs-PAT problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68781050/7976758

Comment: @ElpieKay github provides access to git repos through an svn client (as crazy as it may sound :-D). The question is _definitely_ not git-related.

Comment: Make sure that you don't copy-paste any extra whitespace characters into the password field. I had a similar problem when I copy-pasted my PAT from GitHub. See bottom paragraph of the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/68516312/761095.